# "[message] => DB Error: no such table" error after installing civicrm

Tags: installation

I drupal version 9.3.5 I have installed CiviCRM 5.47.3 plugin using composer in the centos 8 servers.

After installing CiviCRM on the server CiviCRM plugin is enabled automatically in the admin extension section

But after configuring CiviCRM no page is loading and facing the below error,

```
Initialization Error

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

    [code] => -18
    [message] => DB Error: no such table
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'civicrm_cidd.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'civicrm_cidd.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info="SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'civicrm_cidd.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]"]
)
```

I installed CiviCRM by referring to the below link https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/

PHP version is v8.0.27

any guide is appreciated if need any more details please comment

Comment: are your civi tables in same db as drupal or not. if not, did you do the additional steps required for that scenario?

Comment: No, I am using the separate DB for CiviCRM and drupal configuration and notables were available in the CiviCRM database. When I navigate to the CiviCRM installation page I am getting the above error. Can you please guide us on how we can install the CiviCRM configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your CiviCRM settings file `web/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php`
is correct. If you are using a separate CiviCRM database (i.e., not using the same database as drupal), this may need to be adjusted and / or deleted and reinstalled.

Also verify the MySQL user has super priveledges.  You should NOT be using root in MySQL, but instead should have a separate user account.